# How can I pass a namespace to a method?

Tags: c#

```
namespace MyOldService
{    
    public MyNewService.AddressList ToPrivateAddressList()
    {
        MyNewService.AddressList privAddrList = new MyNewService.AddressList();

        privAddrList.creator = (MyNewService.AddressListCreator)this.creator;
        privAddrList.listId = this.listId;
        privAddrList.listIdSpecified = this.listIdSpecified;
        privAddrList.listName = this.listName;
        privAddrList.listType = (MyNewService.AddressingMode)this.listType;
        privAddrList.lastModified = this.lastModified;
        privAddrList.lastModifiedSpecified = this.lastModifiedFieldSpecified;

        if (this.siteList != null && this.listType == MyOldService.AddressingMode.XDAddressingModeSiteIDList)
        {
            privAddrList.siteList = new long[this.siteList.Length];
            Array.Copy(this.siteList, privAddrList.siteList, this.siteList.Length);
        }
        ...
```

Originally written to copy a list defined in a SOAP namespace MyOldService to a class of the same layout in a new namespace MyNewService.  The problem is, with soap classes, if I import the MyOldService namespace into a third namespace, say MyOtherAppService, then my AddressList class becomes a member of that third namespace and is referenced as such.

So, rather than duplicating the code, I'd like to decorate it (or adjust it somehow) with something akin to generics (which I understand won't work because I'm altering the namespace, not just one fixed type [there are multiple types I need from each namespace, as can be seen from the snippet]) to allow this to convert the address list to the corresponding class in whichever namespace is needed.  Possible?

**Edit**: In response to some of the comments below, I'll try to define a better example of what I'm trying to do.

Three classes imported from WSDLs via web references (no, these won't compile, just examples for illustration).  The classes AddressList all have the same layout.

```
namespace A
{    
    enum Mode {};
    enum Creator {};

    class ATypeClass {}

    public partial class AddressList
    {
        int id;
        enum Mode mode;
        enum Creator creator
        long[] siteList;
        ATypeClass[] cspList;
    }
}

namespace B
{    
    enum Mode {};
    enum Creator {};

    class BTypeClass {}

    public partial class AddressList
    {
        int id;
        enum Mode mode;
        enum Creator creator
        long[] siteList;
        BTypeClass[] cspList;
    }
}

namespace C
{    
    enum Mode {};
    enum Creator {};

    class CTypeClass {}

    public partial class AddressList
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        enum Mode mode;
        enum Creator creator
        long[] siteList;
        CTypeClass[] cspList;
    }
}
```

I'll extend the partial class in namespace A with a new method:

```
namespace A
{
    public partial class AddressList
    {
        public T.AddressList ToPrivateAddressList<T>()
        {
            T.AddressList privAddrList = new T.AddressList();

            privAddrList.creator = (T.Creator)this.creator;
            privAddrList.id = this.id;
            privAddrList.name = this.name;
            privAddrList.mode = (T.Mode)this.mode;

            if (this.siteList != null && this.listType == Mode.XDAddressingModeSiteIDList)
            {
                privAddrList.siteList = new long[this.siteList.Length];
                Array.Copy(this.siteList, privAddrList.siteList, this.siteList.Length);
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that part of the problem, in addition to the classes each part of a different namespace, are the enums that are also from the varying namespaces.

Finally, I envision calling it like so (though I know I can't actually do this, I'm looking for a solution that's roughly as elegant):

```
B.AddressList al1 = A.AddressList.ToPrivateAddressList<B>();
C.AddressList al1 = A.AddressList.ToPrivateAddressList<C>();
```

Comment: Where is the problem with referencing? You can always reference a class with its full name (namespacename.classname), right?

Comment: I think he wants to be able to be able to ref the Address class without a fqn

Comment: @payo: I don't think this convenience is worth extra code :)

Comment: @Vlad regardless, I think that's what he's asking

Comment: Copy/paste mistake? `enum Mode mode;` is not a valid field declaration. Remove `enum` and it compiles.

Comment: No, that code was not meant to compile, rather it was meant to illustrate what I want to do, which is to have the method ToPrivateAddressList accept a namespace (a SOAP namespace, imported from a web reference) so that it can generate a class to be returned that belongs to that (passed in) namespace.  I know I can duplicate the code (which is what I've done at the moment) and just declare the appropriate return namespace.class, but that just seems so inelegant if there's a way to do it smarter.  It seems there *should* be, I just don't see what that is at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is an interface and the `where` keyword in the generic type definition.

From your code I see that you have this:

- a method that converts type A to type B
- it does this by assigning properties with the same name
- and then returns the new type B
- the types can reside in different namespaces (but currently have the same name)
- classes are `partial`

Instead of relying on the same name (which you can, using reflection you can achieve the effect you want), you should let each class implement an interface that contains the common properties. This way, you retain compile time type-safety:

```
public interface ICommonAddress 
{
    int id { get; set; }
    Mode mode { get; set; }
    Creator creator { get; set; }
    long[] siteList { get; set; }
    ICommonAddress CreateAddress();
}
```

You can now refactor your classes like this (of course, you'll have to change your fields into properties, but I'm assuming you have them as properties already:

```
// if your original partial class is auto-generated, it is ok to place 
// this definition in another file, it'll still work as long as 
// namespace, classname and compile-unit (must be in same project) are the same
public partial class AddressList : ICommonAddress
{
    int id { get; set; }
    Mode mode { get; set; }
    Creator creator { get; set; }
    long[] siteList { get; set; }
    ATypeClass[] cspList;

    ICommonAddress CreateAddress()
    {
        return new AddressList();   // NOTE: you can even have your ctor private!
    }
}
```

If you do that for each AddressList type you have, you can change your generic method as follows, and it will automatically work, including the IntelliSense showing you the common available properties. Also, implement it as an extension method, so that it applies to all your AddressList types (this is in your case better than using `partial`):

```
public T ToPrivateAddressList<T>(this ICommonAddress _this)
    where T: ICommonAddress
{
    T privAddrList = _this.CreateAddress();

    // this now works normally, without casting
    privAddrList.creator = _this.creator;
    privAddrList.id = _this.id;
    privAddrList.name = _this.name;
    privAddrList.mode = _this.mode;
}
```

Now, if you import a reference to this extension method, you can call `ToPrivateAddressList()` on any type that you have:

```
A.AddressList a_address = A.AddressList.CreateAddress();   // or new A.AddressList()
B.AddressList al1 = a_address.ToPrivateAddressList<B.AddressList>();
C.AddressList al1 = a_address.AddressList.ToPrivateAddressList<C.AddressList>();
```

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this, however the one caveat that might get in the way here, is the A, B and C namespaces (each with the associated AddressList class) are imported from WSDL files via web references... so the fields, enums and such are automatically defined for me during import.  I defined the classes in a gSOAP definition file, built the WSDL then imported it into the current application.  Now, I suppose I could do a one-time import then modify the files that are generated for me, but we prefer to not modify auto-generated code.

Comment: @Jon: that's fine. That's why auto-generated classes usually contain `partial` class-definitions and considering your question, I believe yours do also. Even if one partial definition doesn't and another does contain `: ICommonAddress`, it doesn't matter, as long as the combined class contains an implementation of the interface. Place them in a separate file and you can keep your autogenerated classes untouched. (EDIT: I edited the answer to reflect this).

Comment: That looks quite interesting! I'll have to read up on extension methods as I've never dealt with them before so I'm not familiar with the method signature you wrote.  Will investigate further tomorrow!

Comment: Hmm... ran into a snag.  Thanks to a quirk of gSOAP, arrays of same-named types, but in different namespaces, are given the same name, in the same namespace, in the resulting wsdl file.  IOW given the arrays:

`class PrvCSPArray
{
public:
    A__CSP*     __ptr       0:500;
    int         __size;
};

class PubCSPArray
{
public:
    B__CSP*     __ptr       0:500;
    int         __size;
};`
then both arrays will be named 'ArrayOfCSP' in the wsdl file, leading to a webref import failure. So, how to copy the cspList array in the generic method since those arrays aren't in the interface.

Comment: @Jon: that seems unrelated to the current thread. If you want help on that, I suggest you post a separate question, that's going to give you a larger chance on good answers. One thing though: if something ends up "the same namespace, the same name" it clearly cannot compile, so you need to configure your import differently.

Comment: Hi Abel,  thanks for your good advice.  The problem has gone away, for the most part.  One of the duplicated classes no longer is required to be duplicated (thankfully) so I just now need the one "copy method".  I'll mark your answer as accepted because it looks like it would do the trick and is well thought-out; though I haven't been able to get to a point where I could test it (thanks to gSOAP).

Answer (score 0):

If I right undesrtood your problem you have

```
namespace A
{
    public class MyClass {... }
}
```

and

```
namepsace B
{  
   public class MyClass {...}
}
```

Your question is: how can I define something "generic" that in the same function sometimes deals with `A.MyClass` and other cases `B.MyClass`.

If you think about namespaces like a *part of the type definition*, I think the story becomes clear.
Like if you have 2 different types and want to have one generic that works with both of them. That generic class *knows* when to choose `A.MyClass` method, and when to choose `B.MyClass` method.

If it's not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: See my first post, I've trie4d to clarify what it is I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you can do this:

```
namespace Old
{
  public New.Address Foo()
  {
    New.Address result;
    //...
    return result;
  }
}
```

Without having to say 'New.' on each occurrence of Address? But if you don't, the code uses `Old.Address`?

Can you remove Old.Address from the build/linking of this project (with this code)?

Comment: I've made some additional notes in the first post.